# Jquery autocomplete not getting fired in dynamically loaded partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem getting a jquery executed in my parial view which loaded dynamically.

### Parial View

```
<input type="text" id="producerSearch" select-box-search-performer="true" select-box-search-url="TestUrl" select-box-search-performertype="Producer" select-box-search-destination="#Destination")" />
```

### Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        $(":input[select-box-search-performer]").each(function () {
            var $element = $(this);
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function (request) {
                    var url = $element.attr("select-box-search-url");
                    var destSelect = $element.attr("select-box-search-destination");
                    var performertype =  $element.attr("select-box-search-performertype");
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: { "term": request.term, "productId":  @Model.ProductModel.ProductId, "performerType": performertype},
                        success: function (data) {
                            $(destSelect).empty();
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                                $(destSelect).
                                    append($("<option></option>").attr("value", data[i].ID).text(data[i].Name));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Some of the discussions say "ajaxSuccess need to be included (as the code above). However this does not fire the jquery on dynamically loaded partial view.

-Alan-

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want trigger an ajax call and write the response in a custom destination?

Comment: the above code (without "ajaxSucess" ) works fine for a partial view which is pre loaded. What it does is as you type in a input text , it should fills up the select (autocomplete). It doesn't work when I load the partial view by clicking button

Comment: and are you sure about your selectors?
`select-box-search-destination="Destination"` which you assign to `var destSelect = $element.attr("select-box-search-destination");` and then `$(destSelect).empty();`, shouldn't it be `$('#' + destSelect).empty();`, which is how jQuery selects an element by it's id.

Comment: You are right. But it was typo and i have edited my question.

Comment: have you tried $(document).ready instead of ajaxSuccess?

Comment: Tried that too but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Well I think since you have a partial view, which is loaded dynamically. And since dynamic content loading is an ajax business, so whenever you load the dynamic view firstly the content is loaded and secondly the **ajaxsuccess** is triggered, so `$(":input[select-box-search-performer]").each(function)` works and that time, and not before that.

What you need to do is that you should check the logic which renders dynamic view, and trigger a callback from there when partial view has rendered, and then execute this code.